# WebDAV mapped drive asking for username and password

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, webdav

Since we migrated domains we're having problems with mapping a drive using a WebDAV connection in our login script. It's a simple

```
net use x: \\server.domain.com\folder
```

Which used to authenticate automatically (all we needed to do to make this happen was to put the server in the intranet zone in the internet explorer settings).

Since the domain migration though, nearly everyone is being prompted for a username and password to connect. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? Any help much appreciated.

The webdav share is on a Windows 2003 server running IIS.

Comment: If you could update the question with which version of Windows you're using that'll help. It changes dramatically between Win2003 and Win2008.

Comment: cheers, updated

Answer (score 1):

(Obviously, this has been sitting here awhile. If you have already solved the problem I've love to hear how you did it...)

You mention a "domain migration". If the Windows Server 2003 machine hosting the WebDAV share isn't a domain controller (which it probably isn't), the NetBIOS name of the domain changed, *and* you're using basic authentication you may find that changing the domain name specified in the basic authentication properties for the WebDAV share will help.

That aside, I'd start sniffing traffic. First I'd look at the authentication between the client and the WebDAV server. Ideally you're not authenticating in cleartext, but it'd still be nice to see what's hitting the wire.

After that, I'd crank up auditing on the WebDAV server and see what hits the Security Event Log.

Finally, I'd consider sniffing the traffic on the WebDAV server out to domain controllers during an authentication attempt, just to see if everything there jibes with what you expect to be happening.